# How can search the files that I'm returning below

Tags: python, paramiko

In this code below, I'm using Paramiko to login remotely to an embedded site server and retrieve all .log and .txt files and place them in a folder on my local machine to search for potential pin # that may be in the clear. In the second piece of code, this is part of a script that can unzip .tgz files and perform searches of strings in ascii, hex, etc.... I find that getting the files remotely is not cost effective, and think it's better to just search for all .log and .txt on the embedded device while logged in. However, I'm still a Python novice and it took me a long time to come up with the code that I use now. I'm asking for assistance for the sake of time. Can someone tell me how I would use the code below to implement more exec_commands (I already have the code to search - below the 1st code)? I'm just unsure of where and how to implement it. Thanks!

```
 import paramiko
 import sys
 import os
 import re



 sim_ip = raw_input('Host: ')
 pattern = r"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"


 if re.match(pattern, sim_ip):

     ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
     ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
     ssh.connect(sim_ip, username='root', password='******')
     apath = '/'
     apattern = '"*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' 
     rawcommand = 'find {path} -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' #{pattern}
     command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
     stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
     filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
     ftp = ssh.open_sftp() 
     for afile in filelist:
        (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
        print(filename)
        #ftp.get(afile, 'c:\\Extracted\\' + filename)  #'./'+filename)

     ftp.close()
     ssh.close()

 else:
    print "You entered an invalid IP Address!!!"
```

Here is the code that I currently use to search log and text files:

```
 print "\nDirectory to be searched: " + directory
      print "\nFile result2.log will be created in: c:\Temp_log_files."
      paths = "c:\\Temp_log_files\\result2.log"
      temp = file(paths, "w")
      userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
      userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
      userStrASCII = ''.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
      regex = re.compile(r"(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII )))
      goby = raw_input("Press Enter to begin search (search ignores whitespace)!\n")


      for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
          for file1 in files:
              if file1.endswith(".log") or file1.endswith(".txt"):
                 f=open(os.path.join(root, file1))
                 for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                     result = regex.search(line)
                     if result:
                         ln = str(i)
                         pathnm = os.path.join(root,file1)

                         template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
                         output = template.format(ln, pathnm, result.group())
                         print output
                         temp.write(output)
                         break    
                 else:
                    print "String Not Found in: " + os.path.join(root,file1)
                    temp.write("\nString Not Found: " + os.path.join(root,file1) + "\n")



                 f.close()
      re.purge()
```

Comment: Is your question that you want to execute a Python script on a remote server?

Comment: @Mikko Ohtamaa - I guess you can say that.

Comment: I figure it out, and will post the code shortly.

Answer (score 0):

paramiko has inbuilt classes that do exactly what you're trying to do in your first code section.

```
apath = '/'
apattern = '"*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' 
rawcommand = 'find {path} -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.log"' #{pattern}
command = rawcommand.format(path=apath, pattern=apattern)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
filelist = stdout.read().splitlines()
ftp = ssh.open_sftp() 
for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    print(filename)
    #ftp.get(afile, 'c:\\Extracted\\' + filename)  #'./'+filename)
```

Can be boiled down to

```
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()

for files in ftp.listdir():
    if os.path.splitext(files) in ('.log','.txt'):
        print os.path.split(files)[1]
```

Read their API documentation: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/

Comment: I think you should read the API and read what I'm trying to achieve again ... you will find limits in what you "... boiled down to."

Answer (score 0):

According to what I read in [this page](http://www.siteduzero.com/forum-83-604076-p1-fonction-ssh2-exec.html), when one wants several commands to be executed, each command must be written in `exec_command()` on a distinct line.
But I don't know if this would work:

```
command1 = ............
command2 = ..........
command3 = ...............
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('\n'.join((command1,command2,command3)))
```

or

```
command1 = ............
command2 = ..........
command3 = ...............
allcomands = '''%s
%s
%s'''
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(allcommands % (command1,command2,command3)))
```

I've just discovered Paramiko thanks to your question.
What SSH2 site could I use to run your code ? I have no SFTP or other type account to perform real essays.

.

I am puzzled by the fact you write 'find' in the definition of a command
I didn't see this command among lists of SSH2 and SFTP commands
What 'find' correspond to ?

Comment: @user706808 I had understood that the process is to connect to remote PC or server. And then ?

Comment: that's a bash command that I'm executing via Python (Paramiko), to be executed on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: 'find' is a bash command that I'm executing via Python (Paramiko), to be executed on an Ubuntu server. It searches the entire file system for all .log and .txt files on an embedded Linux server and returns a list of the file path and the particular file.

Comment: @user706808 Thank you. I suppose you have an hired account on the Ubuntu server: I can't try to connect to it and execute your code without signing up ? What is this Ubuntu server ? , I'd like to examine if I could sign up for a limited time, I'm interested to learn about Paramiko. - Concerning my suggestion (writing different commands on distinct lines), it brings no interest ?

Comment: it's a local machine, here at my person. Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu server are both available downloads (open license) ... try them out.

Comment: @user706808 You mean that you want to execute your codes on a machine A to communicate with a machine B via SSH2 protocol , the two machines being in the same LAN ? Alas, I have only one PC for the moment.

Comment: @eyquem let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2778/discussion-between-user706808-and-eyquem)